# Rebase branch on master

Tags: github, git-rebase

I'm a "git rebaser" newbie and I would like to do something specific:

1. I forked wordpress: https://github.com/atelierdesmedias/WordPress
2. I locally checkout version 4.0.1
3. I create the branch prod

Now I would like that my master branch be equals to the prod so people visiting my custom wordpress page on github could see my specific README.

How can I do that?

Comment: If I rephrase, you want to put your prod=>Readme.md to master?

Comment: I dont want to have the lastest modification in master: I want my master to be version 4.0.1 + my custom modification

Comment: Then (maybe it's a stupid question) why don't you just merge 4.0.1 and prod in master ?

Comment: because I don't want the latest modification between 4.0.1 and the upstream master

Comment: I'll manage to do the update like this: 'git merge 4.1.1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want the latest modification between 4.0.1 and the upstream master

Assuming you:

- made your change in your own branch from 4.0.1
- create your own local prod from the same 4.0.1

Then yes, a simple merge from a tag (4.1.1) set on your feature branch to your local prod is enough.

It can be considered a bad practice to work on branches (like "prod") common between your fork and the original repository, but since you do not intent to contribute back, that shouldn't be an issue.